# Missing return statement error in a method

Tags: java, return

I am trying to write a static method that returns a string of my computer's MAC address (the function itself was found here: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-get-mac-address-in-java/). I am having issues with the `return` aspect of the static function. The error I get is the `missing return statement`. How do I remedy this?

```
static String returnMacAddress(){
        InetAddress ip;
        try{
            ip = InetAddress.getLocalHost();

            NetworkInterface network = NetworkInterface.getByInetAddress(ip);
            byte[] mac = network.getHardwareAddress();

            System.out.print("Current MAC address: ");

            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            for(int i = 0; i < mac.length; i++){
                stringBuilder.append(String.format("%02X%s", mac[i], (i < mac.length - 1) ? "-" : ""));
            }
            return stringBuilder.toString();
        }catch(UnknownHostException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch(SocketException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What does the method return if you get an `UnknownHostException` or `SocketException`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All branches must return something, just add a `return null;` at the end:

```
static String returnMacAddress(){             // 1.
    InetAddress ip;
    try{                                      // 2.
        ip = InetAddress.getLocalHost();      // 3. (until return stmt)

        NetworkInterface network = NetworkInterface.getByInetAddress(ip);
        byte[] mac = network.getHardwareAddress();

        System.out.print("Current MAC address: ");

        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        for(int i = 0; i < mac.length; i++){
            stringBuilder.append(String.format("%02X%s", mac[i], (i < mac.length - 1) ? "-" : ""));
        }
        return stringBuilder.toString();       // 4.
    }catch(UnknownHostException e){            // 5.
        e.printStackTrace();                   // 6.
    } catch(SocketException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;                               // 7.
}
```

This is **syntactically** correct - but you have to think about what this means **semantically**, and if that is the desired operation:

- exceptions - do you really just want to print them on System.err?

  - do you want to print them at all, if you just need the address if it is valid?
- would you rather have a String returned representing the condition that it was not successful ot obtain the MAC address?

**EDIT**
How the control flows in this case - as OP asked if the `return null` at the end would negate the previous value, in a successful execution:

- enter method - new stack frame (1. in code)

  - enter try block (2. in code)

    - process instructions in try (3. in code)
    - return statement: stop execution of block, the value is returned to the previous stack frame (4. in code)
    - (not a case now, but if there was a `finally` block, that would be executed now, and that could even overwrite the returned value...)
- execution of the method that called continues with returned value

In unsuccessful case, (UnknownHostException for example):

- enter method - new stack frame (1. in code)

  - enter try block (2. in code)

    - process instructions in try (3. in code)
    - exception thrown
  - enter catch block (5. in code)

    - process catch block (log exception, 6. in code)
    - (not a case now, but if there was a `finally` block, that would be executed now, and that could even overwrite the returned value...)
  - return null statement: stop execution of block, the `null` value is returned to the previous stack frame (7. in code)
- execution of the method that called continues with returned value

As you see, in successful case, the `return null;` statement, even though it is after the "real return", doesn't influence the returned value. Whenever a return is reached, the eecution of the current block is stopped. (and if there is one in the actual context, the appropriate finally block will get the control).

The `finally` block is tricky though: read up on that, it will be useful knowledge.

Comment: Thank you very much good sir. Can you explain a bit to me the importance of return null? Would this invalidate my method by returning a null instead of the String I want?

Comment: I'd suggest making a variable `String address = null;` before the block, `address = stringBuilder.toString();` inside, and `return address;` at the end.

Comment: @Kevin I thought of that (In fact, I think of such in 8 hours a day :) ), but my _opinion_ it is better to see null directly. For me it immediately sends the signal "hey, this method can return null" without having to parse the whole thing.

Comment: I see your point, though I generally assume a method will return null if it encounters an error (maybe too much c programming).

Comment: @Kevin is there such as too much C? :) Jokes apart: it is just an opinion, a personal preference - we all have to code the way it benefits the group the most...

Comment: @theGreenCabbage I tried to add some explanation I hope it is clear

Comment: That was way more comprehensive than I thought. Thank for the information!